# Подключение стандартного окна редактирования контакта

Tags: android

У меня есть ListView со списком контактов, мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на конкретный контакт запускалось стандартное намерение редактирования этого контакта (которое есть в стандартном менеджере контактов). Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI + "/" + contactId));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Где `contactId` - идентификатор контакта в таблице контактов.

Comment: Спасибо, а как получить окно добавления нового контакта?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Если этот вопрос принят - нажмите галочку под вопросом.